# Highlight the field that matched an _all query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to deliver a POC very fast, because of that i decided to just throw all my information into 1 index.

Now, when i search, for example, a number with a _all query, i get a very large document.

Is there a way for elastic to highlight on which field the matching occurred?

I look into these [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) [docs2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) [docs3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#field-match)

But these solutions only highlights a certain field. in my query i use _all, i dont know which field will hit

Is splitting my index into several indexes \ several types on the same index the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#highlighting-all-field:

> A field can only be used for highlighting if the original string value is available, either from the `_source` field or as a stored field.
>
> The `_all` field is not present in the `_source` field and it is not stored by default, and so cannot be highlighted. There are two options. Either [store the _all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#all-field-store) or highlight the [original fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#all-highlight-fields).